# Как исправить ошибку в FFmpeg

Tags: c, centos, ffmpeg

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты. может кто нибудь подскажет что сделать

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/dvb/frontend.h>
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libswscale/swscale.h"
#include "libavdevice/avdevice.h"

static struct dtv_property props[] = {
{ .cmd = DTV_DELIVERY_SYSTEM, .u.data = SYS_DVBT2 },
{ .cmd = DTV_FREQUENCY,       .u.data = 474000000 },
{ .cmd = DTV_MODULATION,      .u.data = QAM_64 },
{ .cmd = DTV_INVERSION,       .u.data = INVERSION_AUTO },
{ .cmd = DTV_INNER_FEC,       .u.data = FEC_AUTO },
{ .cmd = DTV_TUNE }
};

static struct dtv_properties dtv_prop = {
.num = 6, .props = props
};

int main(void)
{
char *fd = open("/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0", O_RDWR);
/*
if (!fd) {
    perror ("open");
    return -1;
}
if (ioctl(fd, FE_SET_PROPERTY, &dtv_prop) == -1) {
    perror("ioctl");
    return -1;
}
printf("Frontend set\\n");
*/

avdevice_register_all();
av_register_all();
avcodec_register_all();
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;


if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, fd, NULL, NULL)!=0)
{
    printf("error");
    return -1;
}

return 0;
}
```

1.будет ли этот код работать нормально с DVB INPUT ?
2.дает ошибку

```
libavdevice.a(xcbgrab.o)||undefined reference to symbol'xcb_setup_pixmap_formats_length'
```

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что ошибка в FFmpeg? Вы при сборке библиотеки подключаете необходимые?

Comment: PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib -ldl" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libfdk_aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-nonfree

Comment: я что-то упустил?

Comment: Вы configure-скрипт для единственного файла-исходника используете? Ну тогда смотрите в Makefile какие библиотеки реально будут подключены. Ищите библиотеку, в которой есть нужная функция и подключайте ее...

Comment: у меня все подклюень. XCB тоже есть. никак не смог заработать этот код